# As for a string of 11 numbers in cpf format

Tags: apex, visualforce

suppose i have a string of 14 numbers, and i want to print it in a vfp in cpf format, how can i do that? in this case I'm receiving this string in the custom controller and I have to show the cpf in 111.111.111-11 format. It's a basic problem, but i'm starting now in salesforce and would appreciate any help :)

Controller:

```
       system.debug('idOpp= '+idOpp);
        if(endereco == null) {
            endereco = [SELECT Id, 
                             Recibidor__r.Numero__c, owner.lastname,
                            owner.Email,owner.CPF__c 
                FROM Opp
                WHERE Id =: idOpp
                LIMIT 1];
        }
        return endereco;
    
    }

VFP:
 <tr><th><b>CPF:&nbsp;</b></th>
 <td></td>   
 </tr>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is "CPF" format? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] to add details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SFSE. I believe you'll want to use `<apex:outputText>` along with a corresponding number format, but I'm not sure that's going to work when you've got a `String` in the controller and multiple `.`s in the output.

Your best bet is probably to write an Apex method that takes a `String` parameter, and builds up the output you want, using `substr` and the like:

```
public static String formatCPF(String cpf) {

  if(cpf.length() < 11) {
    return 'Invalid CPF';
  }

  return cpf.substring(0, 3) + '.' +
         cpf.substring(3, 6) + '.' +
         cpf.substring(6, 9) + '-' +
         cpf.substring(9, 11);
}
```

Please note this is an extremely naive implementation based on the assumption that a CPF is always strictly in this format and is always 11 digits long etc.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started. Put the value returned by this method into a String property on the controller, e.g. `formattedCPF`, then render that in the page with `<apex:outputText value="{!formattedCPF}"/>`.

Comment: thank you very much, i keep picking up on something else now lol
I believe it's always like this when learning a new language

Comment: Oh it absolutely is! Again, welcome to the site - the community can be quite unforgiving at times WRT to question format. In this case it wasn't clear if CPF format is always `111.111.111-11` or if it can be other things, but personally I felt there was enough info to at least provide some guidance so I've re-opened it. Please do stick around :)